# Ruby update hash of hash strange behavior

Tags: ruby, hash

I have created a hash of hash with the hour of the day being the key to a hash with id => zero.

For instance:

```
{0=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 1=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 
    2=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 3=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 
    4=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 5=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 
    6=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 7=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 
    8=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 9=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 
    10=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 11=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 
    12=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 13=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 
    14=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 15=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 
    16=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 17=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 
    18=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 19=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 
    20=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 21=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 
    22=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0},  23=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}}
```

I used this code to create them:

```
hour_hash = {}
count = (1..4).inject({}) {|m,e| m[e]=0;m}
(0..23).each do |i|
    hour_hash[i]=count
end
```

When I try to update the element in one of the hash, like so:

```
hour_hash[0][3] += 1
```

The entire hash get updated:

```
{0=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 1=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 
 2=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 3=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 
 4=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 5=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 
 6=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 7=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 
 8=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 9=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 
 10=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 11=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 
 12=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 13=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 
 14=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 15=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 
 16=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 17=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 
 18=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 19=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 
 20=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 21=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 
 22=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 23=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}}
```

Can someone enlighten me? I should be able to access a single element in the hash, like hash[x][y], right? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You only have two hashes here - the outer one contains 24 references to a single inner one. Just change `hour_hash[i]=count` to `hour_hash[i]=count.clone` to fix it (assuming you actually want 24 *different* internal hashes)

Comment: It is because you assign the Hash `count` to every hour. They all *share* the same instance, so if you update one you update them all. If you create your Hash like this it will work: `Hash[(0..23).map { |h| [h, Hash[(0..4).map { |id| [id, 0] }]] }]`

Comment: This is a rather odd construct. What is it that you are trying to do? Perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: When framing questions that include an example (and an example is always desirable), simplify the example as much as you can.  Here it could be just `hash = { 0=>{ 1=>0 }, 1=>{ 1=>0 } }`.  Notice that I also included the variable `hash`.  That's so answers can make reference to `hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hour_hash = (0..23).each_with_object({}) do |i, h|
  h[i] = (1..4).each_with_object({}){|j, h| h[j] = 0}
end

hour_hash[0][3] += 1

hour_hash # =>
```

> {0=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>1, 4=>0}, 1=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 2=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 3=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 4=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 5=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 6=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 7=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 8=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 9=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 10=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 11=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 12=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 13=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 14=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 15=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 16=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 17=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 18=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 19=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 20=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 21=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 22=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}, 23=>{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}}

Comment: I believe you can simplify line 2 to `h[i] = {1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}` (`hour_hash[0].object_id=> 2172675340`, `hour_hash[1].object_id
=> 2172675320`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland You can go either way. It is a matter of choice. Since the OP used an iteration for creating the inner hash, I used it as well. I minimally changed the OP's code to focus on the point in question. My point was to tell that, whatever code is used to generate the inner hash, it has to be executed each time. Actually, before posting this answer, I had an exactly the same answer as kardeiz' in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use Hash's default values block here:

```
hour_hash = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = {1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0 } }
```

If you just need to look up values, you could stop here. If you need "empty" values for `0..23` you could add:

```
(0..23).each {|x| hour_hash[x] }
```

And use it like:

```
hour_hash[0][3] += 1
```

Comment: Good suggesting.  Just don't forget to use `hour_hash.key?(k)` rather than `hour_hash[k].nil?` to determine if the hash has a key `k`.